# Can someone explain how my teacher found a formula for the nth partial sum of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I'm trying to understand how he did this. Can someone explain this to me step by step?

Did he combine $(-1)^{n-1} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ together?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series). Perhaps you have been taught that

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n r^i = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}. $$

In the link it is described how it is derived.

Comment: I do not understand this formula. I thought the formula was a(1-r^n)/1-r

Comment: @Elsa If you state the formula you know, I can tweak my answer using what you already know.

Comment: Ok I know an = 1 and r = -1/2, but how do I write a formula?

Comment: I mean, you must have been taught for example that
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}ar^i = a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r} $$
or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply $(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n)$ and $(1-x)$ together and see what happens.

Comment: Where did u get 1-x?

Comment: It's a trick. If you multiply these you get $1-x^{n+1}$.  Therefore $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.

Comment: You really have to go through the trouble of multiplying these two things together to see what happens, in order to understand.  You see all the middle terms cancel.  That's the magic of the geometric progression.

Comment: To be more concrete, just think about why
$$\frac19=0.11111111111111111\dots$$
So.. say $s=0.11111111111111\dots$. Then multiply $s$ by $10$, so
$10s=1.11111111111\dots$. Now subtract them to get $9s=1$... The same trick, the same story.

Answer (score 0):

I think these sort of manipulations are much easier to understand using $\sum$ notation than e.g. $+\cdots+$.

If $x$ is a real number with $x\ne 1$, let $$s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k.$$

Then $$xs_n = x\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x^k,$$

hence

$$(1-x)s_n = s_n - xs_n  = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} x^k = x^0 - x^{n+1} = 1-x^{n+1}.$$

Dividing both sides by $1-x$, we obtain

$$s_n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$

If $|x|<1$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{n+1}=0, $$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = \frac1{1-x}. $$

This probably seems like magic at first, but after you do it enough times it becomes second nature. It's important enough that you should know the result as well as the derivation. It will serve you well in calculus, combinatorics, probability, $\ldots$